# How to detect touches on a skspritenode created in a separate scene using a custom class of that node

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift3, skspritenode

So basically I have a node called tree and I designed it in a .sks file.

I added a custom class for the skspritenode but the custom class doesn't seem to affect the node.

I am trying to detect touches on the node and its children.

This node is being transfered to multiple scenes using `removefromparent()` and `addchild()` functions so instead of writing duplicate code on each scene to detect the touch I am trying to use the custom node class to do it... any help would be appreciated.

note i have super.init function with the texture as it is necessary but I would like to use the node that was already created in the scene.

**My class code**

```
import SpriteKit

class tree: SKSpriteNode {

    init() {
        let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "tree")
        super.init(texture: texture, color: SKColor.clear, size: texture.size())
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches {
            print("touched!")
        }
    }



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a good explanation in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27912898/1894067) answer that should be clear your ideas about **SKS** files and subclassing.
About your code it is a good habit to use uppercase letter for the class names, in your case I prefer to use `class Tree` instead of class tree.
About your second issue, you can use [userData](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/sknode/1483121-userdata) to transfer your object from a scene to another as explained below in my example:

```
import SpriteKit
class GameScene: SKScene {
    private var label : SKLabelNode?
    var tree : Tree!
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        self.label = self.childNode(withName: "//helloLabel") as? SKLabelNode
        if let label = self.label {
            label.alpha = 0.0
            label.run(SKAction.fadeIn(withDuration: 2.0))
        }
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        tree = Tree()
        tree.name = "tree"
        addChild(tree)
        tree.position = CGPoint(x:self.frame.midX,y:self.frame.midY)
    }
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            let pointOfTouch = touch.location(in: self)
            let nodeUserTapped = atPoint(pointOfTouch)
            if nodeUserTapped.name == "tree" {
                tree.removeFromParent()
                let sceneToMoveTo = Scene2.init(size: self.size)
                sceneToMoveTo.userData = NSMutableDictionary()
                sceneToMoveTo.userData?.setObject(tree, forKey: "tree" as NSCopying)
                let gameTransition = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 0.5)
                self.view!.presentScene(sceneToMoveTo, transition: gameTransition)

            }
        }
    }
}
class Scene2: SKScene {
    var tree:Tree!
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        print("This is the scene: \(type(of:self))")
        guard let previousValue = self.userData?.value(forKey: "tree") else { return }
        if previousValue is Tree {
            tree = previousValue as! Tree
            addChild(tree)
            tree.position = CGPoint(x:self.frame.midX,y:self.frame.midY)
        }
    }
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            let pointOfTouch = touch.location(in: self)
            let nodeUserTapped = atPoint(pointOfTouch)
            if nodeUserTapped.name == "tree" {
                tree.removeFromParent()
                if let sceneToMoveTo = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
                    sceneToMoveTo.scaleMode = .aspectFill
                    sceneToMoveTo.userData = NSMutableDictionary()
                    sceneToMoveTo.userData?.setObject(tree, forKey: "tree" as NSCopying)
                    let gameTransition = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 0.5)
                    self.view!.presentScene(sceneToMoveTo, transition: gameTransition)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can read I've the control of touches both in my parent class and in my node, this can be made possible by changing the `touchesBegan` method of your custom `SKSpriteNode` as:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        print("touched!")
    }
    guard let parent = self.parent else { return }
    parent.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
}
```

Remember that you should extend this approach also to the other touches method if you want to use them..

Comment: Thanks! This definitely helped.